# Multiple files for one argument in argparse Python 2.7

Tags: python, file, parsing, arguments, argparse

**Trying to make an argument in argparse where one can input several file names that can be read.**
In this example, i'm just trying to print each of the file objects to make sure it's working correctly but I get the error:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: f2.txt f3.txt
```

**.  How can I get it to recognize all of them?**

my command in the terminal to run a program and read multiple files

```
python program.py f1.txt f2.txt f3.txt
```

Python script

```
import argparse

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()      
    parser.add_argument('file', nargs='?', type=file)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    for f in args.file:
        print f

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I used `nargs='?'` b/c I want it to be any number of files that can be used . If I change `add_argument` to:

```
parser.add_argument('file', nargs=3)
```

then I can print them as strings but I can't get it to work with '?'

Answer (score 87, accepted):

If your goal is to read **one or more** readable files, you can try this:

```
parser.add_argument('file', type=argparse.FileType('r'), nargs='+')
```

`nargs='+'` gathers all command line arguments into a list. There must also be one or more arguments or an error message will be generated.

`type=argparse.FileType('r')` tries to open each argument as a file for reading. It will generate an error message if argparse cannot open the file. You can use this for checking whether the argument is a valid and readable file.

Alternatively, if your goal is to read **zero or more** readable files, you can simply replace `nargs='+'` with `nargs='*'`. This will give you an empty list if no command line arguments are supplied. Maybe you might want to open stdin if you're not given any files - if so just add `default=[sys.stdin]` as a parameter to `add_argument`.

And then to process the files in the list:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
for f in args.file:
    for line in f:
        # process file...
```

---

More about nargs:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#nargs

More about type: https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#type

Answer (score 0):

Just had to make sure there was at least one argument

```
parser.add_argument('file',nargs='*')
```

Comment: `'*'` means ZERO_OR_MORE. `'+'`, ONE_OR_MORE.  In fact you can use `nargs=argparse.ONE_OR_MORE`, since `argparse` defines a constant with that name.